# Having trouble adding arabic language support to Magento website

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add internationalization features to my Magento E-commerce site. I would like to add a language selection dropdown too the homepage. I have tried using community modules I found such as the arabic language pack extension but I'm getting errors. Can anyone help me solve this problem

Comment: I rewrote you question so that it would be easier to read in English and removed some aspects of it that had little or no bearing on the question itself. I see you mention that you're having errors. It's very helpful when asking for others to help you fix errors to include the errors you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'Store View' from admin panel
Admin Panel => System -> Manage Stores section.
Name it Arabic.
Then Add CSV files from en_US directory to /app/locale/ar_SA with all your Arabic words side by side with English words.

First try with a fresh Magento installation with default template then you can implement in production.